# Solve $\displaystyle S_n(x) = x \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(S_{n-1}(x)) , S_0(x) = e^x, S_n(x) = ?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, delay-differential-equations

$\displaystyle S_n(x) = x \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(S_{n-1}(x)), S_0(x) = e^x$

I would like to know what's the method to solve such recurrences.

This is what I got while trying to find $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{k^n}{k!}} $

All I could think of was comparing coefficients but here it is not a polynomial. I also thought about making patterns but doesn't help.

$\displaystyle S_n(x) + S_{n-1}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xS_{n-1}(x))$

and then if I assume $A_{n-1}(x) = xS_{n-1}(x)$, then recurrence keeps on repeating. That is all I could observe.

Comment: To compute $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^n}{k!}$, the usual road is to note that $S_0=e$ and that the sequence $(S_n)$ solves the relation $S_{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}S_k$ for every $n\geqslant0$. Thus, $S_n=eB_n$ where $B_n$ denotes the $n$th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), see also [Dobiński's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula). Note finally that the exponential generating function of the Bell numbers is known.

Comment: @Did I didn't know that. Thanks. This closes the discussion, I believe. But just out of curiosity, do these kind of recurrences have a method to solve?

Comment: Maybe ( yes, maybe !!! ) you can check the $Generalized\ Exponential\ Integral\ \,\mathrm{E}_{n}\left(\,z\,\right)$ which has some similarities to the present question.   http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19.E12

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer since the result is just based on observation.*

Out of curiosity, I computed the first terms and, as one coud expect, the result is $$S_n(x)=e^x \,P_n(x)$$ Looking at the coefficients, it became quite clear that $$P_n(x)=\sum _{i=1}^n \mathcal{S}_n^{(i)}\, x^i$$ where appear Stirling numbers of the second kind.